# deleting associatied models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I have the following model associations

Customer model

```
class Customer
   has_many :readings
   has_many :invoices
end
```

Reading Model

```
class Reading
  belongs_to :customer
 end
```

Invoice Model

```
class Invoice
   belongs_to :customer
   has_many :invoice_items
end
```

Invoice Items

```
class Invoiceitem
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

Creating a destroy action in my customers_controller deletes the customer however, it leaves a lot of orphaned records making it had for me to call the show action on the invoices controller due to nil values.

How can I be able to delete a customer and all the associated records in the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `:dependent => :destroy` to the `has_many`

The [API Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) section **Deleting from associations** contains this example.

For example:

```
class Author
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
Author.find(1).destroy # => Will destroy all of the author's posts, too
```